В чём разница между согласованием и управлением в подчинительном виде словосочетаний русского языка?
Как достоверно отличить одно от другого?

Agreement (согласование) is a match of some grammatical category between the head (главное слово) and its dependent words in a phrase.
In Russian, these grammatical categories are the number, the case, the gender, and the animacy. If the head changes any of these categories, the dependent words change it too.
An example would be the phrase зелёная креветка: плывёт зелёная креветка, говорить о зелёной креветке, варить зелёные креветки, изучать зелёных креветок. You can see that the dependent word зелёный agrees with the head креветка in case, gender, number, and animacy.
Government (управление) is a requirement set by the head word that (in the case of the Russian language) the dependent word be put into a certain case, and/or used with a certain preposition. Usually, the head is a verb or a deverbal part of speech (a noun, adjective or an adverb formed from a verb).
An example would be the phrase ревновать Колю к Снежане. Here, the verb ревновать governs the accusative in its direct object and the dative (with the preposition к) for its indirect object. The dependent words have their semantic roles that are defined by the cases and the prepositions. The cases and the prepositions don't change as you conjugate the head word: ревную к Снежане, ревнующий к Снежане, ревность к Снежане etc.
The distinguish between agreement and government, find the head word of the phrase and try to change its case, number, or gender.
If the dependent words change as well and in the same way, you have an agreement.
If they don't change (but can in theory), you have a government.
Finally, if they can't change at all, being invariable (e.g. быстро бегать, идти вразвалку etc.), then you have a parataxis (примыкание).
